# Eclipse CSS Editor "Unknown property" after LESS nature mess

Tags: css, eclipse, warnings, css-editor

I'm done with googleing, I have to ask you folks...

I have a static web project (not JavaFX, thus no JavaFX toolkits!) in Eclipse Kepler. Now thats the messy road I went:

- I created a .less file (for the first time)
- Eclipse starts nagging with the "Do you want to add the LESS-project nature?"-popup
- I clicked 'no' 10 times (pops up every time I start Eclipse)
- then I clicked 'yes' to add the nature for making this stop (could not find ANY workaround for that #$%!+"* !)

Now I face this travesty: 
[image]

The built in CSS-editor marks every trivial property as unknown. I have no clue how to fix this. I removed the less-nature and restored my old .project file too but the warnings (and even real errors) persist. I found out that rewriting the properties does not summon these warnings!

No, I won't rewrite ~6000 lines of css...

Please help. Please make it stop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, found the solution (dumb as can be):

- delete project (only!) in Eclipse
- re-import project (which completely revalidates the project structure)
- errors are gone...

Although this solved my problem, I feel uneasy about the fact that I could not find any possibility to do a complete re-validation without to delete and re-import my project. This is pretty nasty...

Answer (score 0):

Right click project *Configure*->*Remove LESS nature*.